# Any example implementation JSON-LD document on a web page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I need to look at any document that has an embedded JSON-LD object in the HTML.

I have embedded a JSON-LD object on my architecture. I have context from 2 sources schema.org and my custom set of vocab with is further negotiated with the scheam.org reference which is www.mysitename/vocab.

Here I have provided a download link with .jsonld file extension. I need to see a reference from any HTML document that has embedded a JSON-LD object in it to get an idea about it.

Below is the embedded JSON-LD object in the source-code of my HTML document:

```html
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": [
        "http://schema.org/",
        "http://puneet.ys/vocab"
    ],
    "@id": "http://puneet.ys/seahawks",
    "@type": "SportsTeam",
    "name": "Seattle Seahawks",
    "url": "http://puneet.ys/seahawks",
    "image": "/2011/12/08/35/team/222398/large.jpg",
    "interactionCount": "124 UserLikes",
    "logo": "/2011/12/08/35/team/222398/large.jpg",
    "description": "The Seattle Seahawks are […]",
    "discipline": "http://puneet.ys/sport/football",
    "subOrganizationOf": "http://puneet.ys/company/nfl",
    "location": {
        "@id": "http://puneet.ys/seattle-wa",
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Seattle, WA",
        "url": "http://puneet.ys/seattle-wa",
        "image": "/2011/12/08/35/city/28545/large.jpg",
        "interactionCount": "25 UserLikes",
        "photo": "/2011/12/08/35/city/28545/large.jpg",
        "sameAs": [
            "http://www.freebase.com/m/0d9jr",
            "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle",
            "http://www.seattle.gov/"
        ]
    },
    "claimedBy": "http://puneet.ys/fan/chris-mccoy",
    "sameAs": [
        "http://www.freebase.com/m/070xg",
        "http://www.facebook.com/Seahawks",
        "http://www.twitter.com/seahawks",
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Seahawks",
        "http://www.seahawks.com"
    ]
}  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [Google Webmaster Tools Answer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4620133) it says:

> The data, enclosed within the `<script type="application/ld+json"> ... </script>` tags as shown in the examples below may be placed in either the `<HEAD>` or `<BODY>` region of the page. Either way, it won’t affect how your document appears in users’ web browsers.

I wrapped your `script` above in `<html><header>` tags and it worked with the [Google Email Markup-Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/), although for some reason the [Google Webmaster Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) doesn't pick up JSON-LD yet.

You can also use [Google's Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper), enter some dummy URL or HTML, click "Start Tagging" (blue button), add at least one tag, then "Create HTML" (red button) and finally change the "Microdata"-dropdown to "JSON-LD".